# The meaning of `There's no way ever you'd use a computer to show it's true.`

Tags: meaning, sentence

Does the sentence:

> There's no way ever you'd use a computer to show it's true.

mean:

> 1. There's some way that I can show it's true by computer
> 2. There's no way that I can show it's true even by computer** ?

(I am an English learner and I am confused about this sentence.)

Comment: The second, almost, but the original sentence has "would" not "can". So it doesn't mean you cannot, but *would* not use a computer for this. For example, you might use a computer to prove that more people worship than don't, but you would never use a computer to prove that what they worship is real.

Comment: Your second sentence is closest, but the *even* puts the wrong emphasis on it. The sentence says nothing about using *other* things. It's only talking about computers. By saying *even* you are making the false assumption that if anything *could* show it's true, a computer would be the best thing to do that. (And as the other comment says, it's *would*, not *can*.)

Comment: Neither. You wouldn't use a computer to prove it is true. A computer is not a tool you would use to demonstrate it is true - you would use a [bucket and spade] to show that it is true.

Answer (score 2):

This sentence is not grammatically correct, so I assume that it was written or spoken by someone in conversation. I could see it meaning one of two things, depending on the context:

> There's no way **you'd ever** use a computer to show it's true.
>   - *Interchange* ever *and* you'd.

This means that you would never show that it's true using a computer.

> There's no way, ever! You'd use a computer to show it's true.
>   - *Add an exclamation point to split it into two sentences.*

The speaker refutes the listener's position, then offers a followup action.

Comment: I've up-voted this since you have correctly pointed out that the sentence is not grammatical. And you have given a corrected version of what it almost certainly means. However I would have left out the second example, as the original was clearly not punctuated that way, and it probably adds further confusion for our Chinese OP to cope with.

Answer (score 1):

It means "One would never use a computer to show that it is true".

We don't have context but it seems the implication is that a computer is the wrong tool for the job.

**There's no way ever** = Not under any circumstances at any time  (i.e. never)

That phrase could be punctuated like this:

**There is no way, ever, (that) you <sup>i.e. "one"</sup> would use a computer to show it is true.**